# Is it possible to execute a Jupyter Notebook file from Jenkins and return a value to it?

Tags: python, jenkins, jupyter-notebook

So I have a navigation project, where I am tracking the movement of the robot on a predetermined map. I also have a notebook file in which I am plotting the various ROS topics by subscribing to them individually. This is all well and good on my personal pc.

I have used rosbag files to store all the ROS topics in the entire simulation. Now if I want to run a Jupyter notebook from Jenkins for this particular rosbag file and get the data from it for plots, how to I go about it?

I have tried using the execute shell, where the command 
`jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute mynotebook.ipynb` 
is supposed to execute my notebook but I keep running into this error 'Error executing Jupyter command 'nbconvert': [Errno 2] No such file or directory'.

The host system has Jupyter Notebook installed and all the other dependencies are present as well. In fact, the same command executes perfectly well from my local command line.

Comment: So figured out what the error in execution was. The jenkins user had to be given permissions to execute the jupyter commands. Now I am able to execute the jupyter notebook. I still need help returning a value from it though. If a value is returned, I want the Jenkins job to stop executing. Help.

Comment: Is `exit` not working with Jenkins? Sometimes that just exits the script, if you want to exit the job you need to exit with a non-zero value (Jenkins will assume a failure and stop the job).

Comment: If that works then you should either post your answer (self-answered questions are allowed) or delete this question. If it doesn't work I would edit this question with the new problem and sample code showing how you are executing the Jenkins call from python.